# центрирование и растягивание на всю ячейку элемента со свойством `position: absolute;` внутри grid-макета

Tags: css, grid

Уже третий час бьюсь над задачей и никак не получается решить.
Есть вертикальный grid-макет. Внутри ячейки грид расположена картинка. Над картинкой надо разместить по центру текст и затенить фон. Текст позиционирую через `position: absolute;`, но он таким образом позиционируется не относительно ячейки, а относительно всего grid-макета.
Подскажите как разместить тест по центру зеленого блока и растянуть текстовый блок на весь зеленый фон (затенить картинку).
Уже  размещал внутри дополнительного блока, пробовал разные способы позиционирования, но результата нет.

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 10em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {background-color: red;}

.two {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;}

.three {background-color: yellow;}

.two img {
    border-radius: 0.05em;
    background-color: #054a71;
    border: 0.2em solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.two h6 {
    display: grid;
    position: absolute;
    justify-items: center;
    left: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="https://jjji.ru/800x550">
    <h6 class="grid-inner">проблемный текст</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключевое слово здесь - "относительно" aka relative:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 10em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
}

.three {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two img {
  border-radius: 0.05em;
  background-color: #054a71;
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.two h6 {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  place-items: center;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="https://jjji.ru/800x550">
    <h6 class="grid-inner">проблемный текст</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Начал переписывать код на CodePen и сам понял в чем ошибка. Спасибо за оперативную помощь! Так и знал, что упускаю какую то мелочь.

Comment: @СтаниславСтрижаков: очень часто в процессе написания вопроса приходит понимание и вопрос отпадает :) Удачи.